# Angular 4 How to use .js

Tags: angular

I'm learning using angular since about a few days now and I have troubles using javascript in it.

The thing is I want to learn how u hide and show elements based on clicks. Something like http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/18972/

but I have no idea where to link the javascript part to make it work.
I've tried putting it in the index.html in the head section `<script src="showhide.js"></script>`
which didn't work also tried it in app.component.html but neither will do the trick also couldn't find this anywhere.

So I hope someone can tell me how to make this work so I can start learning new things.

Comment: In fiddle it's Angular 1.x, but you mention `app.component.html` which is common for Angular 2.x/4.x can you be more specific which version you're using. __In general all .js files are to be included in your index.html__.

Comment: this link might help [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq) with and without typings

Comment: Sorry i thought it was general. i'm using angular 4.x

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use an external library to get a similar navigation with the example you provide.
You can succeed the same behavior with Routes.
You can read more about routing in Angular documentation.

If you want to hide and show divs based on clicks you can use *ngIf directive.

And if the clicks get trigger on different Components read for Event Listeners.